# Does Hibernate make debugging easy?

Tags: hibernate

I know, Hibernate is an ORM that maps objects to table data directly. So does that mean that hibernate make debugging easy? I am a student and self learning hibernate. I came across a program in hibernate where I did not have to use try-catch block as we usually do with JDBC logic that we put in the program. So my question is how the exceptions are handled and is it easy to debug in hibernate than in JDBC?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, Hibernate wraps SQLExceptions in unchecked Hibernate exceptions. So exceptions still get thrown, you just aren't forced to catch them. In practice that is ok because there's usually nothing you can do at runtime about these exceptions anyway, it is a matter of something like the database being unavailable or an invalid HQL statement. Your program should have a place where it catches all exceptions that haven't already gotten handled, where it logs the exception name and stacktrace.

Hibernate can be very useful, but it does not exactly make debugging easy. Hibernate introduces some indirection (reordering how sql statements are executed, introducing a 1st level cache using an identity map, etc.) that can make debugging some things a lot harder. One advantage Hibernate has over JDBC is you don't have the horrible error-prone boilerplate code that you get with JDBC, however you get the same advantage if you use Ibatis (recently renamed to MyBatis) or Spring-JDBC, without the complications that Hibernate introduces.

Personally I like Hibernate a lot, it is very powerful, but it is complex and it will get you into trouble if you do not take the time to understand what's going on. But JDBC isn't even on the list of solutions I'd recommend for most cases, it is a miserable API to code to, and wrapping it in a better library is a problem that has already been solved multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't have to use try/catch blocks around hibernate queries is that the exceptions it throws are unchecked exceptions whereas JDBC queries can throw SQLExceptions which are checked.  You may wish to catch and handle the HibernateExceptions anyway.

It's much easier to program with Hibernate (or another ORM framework) than direct JDBC because it does a lot of the hard work of converting relational data into objects and this will probably mean you have fewer bugs.  But there are many complications and pitfalls with Hibernate as there are in any ORM software tool.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping tables to objects is just one of the features that Hibernate provides. You cannot miss out other important feature like

- caching (both object and query caching)
- Handling Proxy generation and lazy loading of object associations.
- Managing association ( cascading features which help manage life cycles of objects)

As both the answers by @Nathan Hughes and @z7sg Ѫ specify that Hibernate wraps the `SQLExceptions` with `RuntimeExceptions` and hence the we don't have to write sometime ugly and unwanted `try...catch` loops. 
However also Hibernate also allows you to specify a `Dialect` [underlying database] and helps give you customized Exceptions specific to the database being used.It also allows you generate statistical information about the queries being run so that you can improve your data access methodologies.
Checkout [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) for further configuration